# How would one write down this mathematical expression programmatically?

Tags: c, math, lisp

> The sum of f(i) for all integers i =
>   k,  k + 1, .., continuing only as long
>   as the condition p(i) holds.

I'm going for:

```
 for (i = 0; i <= V_COUNT; i++) {
  sum += sine_coeff[i] * pow(E, e_factor[i]) * sin(
    (solar_coeff[i] * solar_anomaly)
    + (lunar_coeff[i] * lunar_anomaly)
    + (moon_coeff[i] * moon_argument)
    );
 }
```

based on the following Common LISP code:

```
         (sigma ((v sine-coeff)
                 (w E-factor)
                 (x solar-coeff)
                 (y lunar-coeff)
                 (z moon-coeff))
                (* v (expt cap-E w)
                   (sin-degrees
                    (+ (* x solar-anomaly)
                       (* y lunar-anomaly)
                       (* z moon-argument)))))))
```

where sigma is:

```
(defmacro sigma (list body)
  ;; TYPE (list-of-pairs (list-of-reals->real))
  ;; TYPE -> real
  ;; $list$ is of the form ((i1 l1)..(in ln)).
  ;; Sum of $body$ for indices i1..in
  ;; running simultaneously thru lists l1..ln.
  `(apply '+ (mapcar (function (lambda
                                 ,(mapcar 'car list)
                                 ,body))
                     ,@(mapcar 'cadr list))))
```

(for full source code, see [Calendrical calculations source code](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item1164334/?site_locale=en_GB)

**Edit**
Thanks for all your answers. Investigating the code examples, I have come to the conclusion that, in programming terms, the author indeed ment that one has to loop over a certain set of values. From that, it was easy to conclude that `p` had to return `False` when it has run out of values, i.e. control has reached the end of the list.

Comment: What do you mean, "how would I write this programatically," when you already have the Common Lisp code in front of your eyes? Insulting :)

Comment: Lol, yes indeed the question is a linguistic fail, since I already have it programmatically ;) The reason I didn't ask "how to translate this to language x" is because I'm trying to understand what actually happens here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a function `p()`, e.g.:

```
bool_t p(int i)
{
   // some conditional code here, that returns TRUE or FALSE
}
```

It seems like you need to loop for an arbitrarily long time (i.e. there's no hard upper limit), and you need to stop looping when `p(i)` returns `FALSE`.  Therefore, you probably want a loop something like this:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = k; p(i); i++)
{
    sum += f(i);
}
```

Depending on how large `i` and `sum` can get, you may want to declare them as `long` rather than `int`.

Comment: or `int64_t`, since `long` often isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
sum = 0;
i = k;
while (p(i))
    sum += f(i++);
```

Comment: @tadeusz thanks, I noticed just at the same time as you commented!!